Retrieving Gas Fee Data for Transactions on the Solana Blockchain
I need to retrieve the gas fee for transactions on the current Solana blockchain. Can you recommend a method or tool that I can use to get this data?

If you want to get transaction fees paid by transactions, you can fetch all transactions with getBlock and then look for meta.fee in each returned transaction.
More information at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getblock#result
